# Prototype mismatch: sub POE::Kernel::F_GETFL () vs none at (eval 33) line 1

Tags: perl

I am getting an error

> Prototype mismatch: sub POE::Kernel::F_GETFL () vs none at (eval 33) line 1

while trying to run perl code in windows 7 using eclipse. I am using the `POE` module in my perl code.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Something to go on? Is this in your program? What is your program doing? Is this a module? Can you show us a bit of code?

Comment: David , I am using POE framework in my perl program. This error is coming from one of the defined module in POE , which is coming from POE::Resource::FileHandles.pm and POE::Kernel.pm. Error is : 

FileHandles.pm

BEGIN {
  if (RUNNING_IN_HELL) {
    eval '*F_GETFL = sub { 0 };';
    eval '*F_SETFL = sub { 0 };';
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I saw the `RUNNING_IN_HELL` and wondered where that came from:

```
BEGIN {
   local $SIG{'__DIE__'} = 'DEFAULT';

    {
         no strict 'refs';
         if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
            *{ __PACKAGE__ . '::RUNNING_IN_HELL' } = sub { 1 };
         } else {
            *{ __PACKAGE__ . '::RUNNING_IN_HELL' } = sub { 0 };
         }
    }
}
```

So, he's defining a constant called `RUNNING_IN_HELL` which is set to *true* if running on Windows.

I see a lot of checks making sure that you have a particular version of Perl, and various modules. It looks like *older* versions of Perl pre-5.10 may be flaky. Any module that defines a constant called `RUNNING_IN_HELL` as true when you run on Windows might have certain issues with Windows.

I suggest getting in touch with [Rocco Caputo](https://metacpan.org/author/RCAPUTO), the module's author and have a nice discussion with him about the inner workings of the module and why you may be getting these errors. It might simply be a condition he has not checked for.

Even then, you will have to show some source code. You have to explain what ***you*** are doing, how ***you*** setup the calls to the modules, and what version of Perl ***you*** are using, and what ***you*** have done in attempts to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Not able to reach "Rocco Caputo" , can sombody help me on this issue.

Comment: David ,after fixing above error , I am getting below error now. (i am running in windows)
Subroutine AUTOLOAD redefined at C:/Perl/site/lib/Time/HiRes.pm line 31.
Subroutine import redefined at C:/Perl/site/lib/Time/HiRes.pm line 49.
Subroutine tv_interval redefined at C:/Perl/site/lib/Time/HiRes.pm line 70.
This code is running fine in linux platform.

Comment: AUTOLOAD is the subroutine for a class that is executed when no other _methods_ can be found. It's a way to quickly build of a set of methods without the bother of actually writing a method. For example, I might define `AUTOLOAD` to assume a method call is a hash key to my class, and use `AUTOLOAD` to do an automatic getter/setter method for that attribute. It looks like this subroutine is getting redefined for this class. Take a look at this file and see if it has multiple AUTOLOAD subroutines and maybe why they're all being reloaded.